# Drag and Drop Elements Update Sort Index Logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Multi select drag and drop elements, changing sortIndex values

I have an array of elements where each element has a sortIndex which is timestamp epoch value of createdAt.Now backend sorts those elements using this timestamp and sends it to frontend in set of 30 by paginating results.

In front end we have an option od multiple select elements and drag and drop feature,where any n number of elements can be selected,dragged and dropped in between any two elements.

What we are currently doing is,we are checking the sortIndexes of the two elements and we are changing the sortindexes of dropped elements in decimals accordinly where least and highest values will not cross the values of sortIndexes of the two elements. And we are sending the updated sortIndexes of dropped elements to backend.
This works fine for some decimals,after few decimals javascript is rounding of the decimals to int.

Is there any solution for this apart from getting all the array of elements and changing their sortIndexes accordingly and sending them back to backend and in backend again changing every sortIndex value in database?

Comment: Have you searched StackOverflow for answers?  there are many threads referencing 'createdat'